# Spacing between "arrow" symbols in Vim Airline

Tags: linux, vim, arch-linux, vim-plugins

I have Vim 8.0 running on Arch Linux (last updated 3rd of January) and have installed the package `powerline-fonts` using pacman as well as vim-airline using Vundle. I have also set `let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1` in `~/.vimrc`. The problem is; there's a tiny gap to the right of the the arrow-like symbols on the right part of the status bar. As can be seen below, this damages the looks of Vim Airline. It does not affect the arrow-like symbols on the left part of the status bar (probably because the spacing is to the right). This seems like a bug to me?! Does anyone know a workaround?

Kind regards.

[image: vim-airline spacing]

EDIT: By the way, this is a nearly minimal `.vimrc` when using Vundle:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

call vundle#end()

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For others encountering similar problems, some hints to how to make this work can be found in the following Github issue:

https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/1637

Notice that vim-airline with powerline fonts is very fragile in the sense that it depends on the exact font settings of your system. There is no attempt to avoid that.